# Is Lazarus auto-completion system avail as a "component"?

Tags: autocomplete, lazarus

I don't know about Lazarus IDE. Anybody knows, can its auto-completion system be available as a separate source code, or dll, or TCP server? Or is it hard-coded into the IDE so others can't use it easily?

I would use such code under Windows if its avail. I need to find auto-completions for Pascal code.

Comment: You might be lucky and find it separately in some [`..\components\codetools`](http://sourceforge.net/p/lazarus/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/components/codetools/) folder unit. Unfortunately I can't suggest you where to start (e.g. the code completion "form" is separately in the [`codecontextform.pas`](http://sourceforge.net/p/lazarus/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ide/codecontextform.pas) unit). I don't even know how much it's hardcoded, however I feel this question might better be asked on Lazarus forums since its developers are answering there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik it is in codetools, it is called codecompletion and it is GPL (which might not suit your purpose).

It is dynamic though (as in the suggestions are not hardcoded or predefined, lazarus scans source in a background task.

Comment: So it is https://sourceforge.net/p/lazarus/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/components/codetools/codecompletiontool.pas